# Sci-fi book: portals appear in London and send a failed artist towards a designated path where he operates a giant superweapon

Tags: story-identification, books

A few years ago I bought a book on my way to another country. I bought the book before the flight at an airport kiosk.

It was a sci-fi book about a failed London artist having a row with his brother over something minor - and then a series of portals appear all over London (and the world I imagine) that sends him towards a designated path.

That ends in the protagonist operating a giant superweapon.

Answer (score 14):

This is [The Recollection](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9766037-the-recollection) by Gareth L. Powell.

> When his brother disappears into a bizarre gateway on a London Underground escalator, failed artist Ed Rico and his brother's wife Alice have to put aside their feelings for each other to go and find him. Their quest through the 'arches' will send them hurtling through time, to new and terrifying alien worlds.

[image: cover of "The Recollection". The cover shows a metallic object entering the atmosphere above a planet, against a starry background.]

Comment: yesss!! thank you, I've been wracking my brain all evening. Lent the book to a "colleague" a few years back and it was never returned to me. Thanks Valorum!

Comment: @ChristianHelgesen - Don't forget to upvote and click the "accepted" button (to the left of the answer) to show that this is the right one.